# Cannot open compressed file when installing R packages

Tags: r

This problem recently came up when I try to install new packages in R 3.2.0.  I noticed it when trying to install vegan, but I seem to get the same message for all packages I try to install, including when I try to install manually from a downloaded tar.gz.  The entire message I get when I try to install any package is:

> utils:::menuInstallPkgs()
>   also installing the dependency ‘permute’
>
> trying URL 'http://cran.us.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/permute_0.8-4.zip'
>   Content type 'application/zip' length 501108 bytes (489 KB)
>   downloaded 489 KB
>
> trying URL 'http://cran.us.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/vegan_2.3-0.zip'
>   Content type 'application/zip' length 2863206 bytes (2.7 MB)
>   downloaded 2.7 MB
>
> Error in read.dcf(file.path(pkgname, "DESCRIPTION"), c("Package", "Type")) : 
>     cannot open the connection
>   In addition: Warning messages:
>   1: In unzip(zipname, exdir = dest) :
>     write error in extracting from zip file
>   2: In read.dcf(file.path(pkgname, "DESCRIPTION"), c("Package", "Type")) :
>     cannot open compressed file 'permute/DESCRIPTION', probable reason 'No such file or directory'

After looking at previous questions, I tried:

> install.packages("vegan", repos="http://cran.us.r-project.org")

but still get the same error.  I also tried to reset the repos with:

> options(repos=c(CRAN="@CRAN@", 
>                    CRANextra="http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin")

But still get the same error, for any package I try to install.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: What mirror are you using?  I live in Singapore, and the local R mirror here has been having problems for a while.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error when there was no space left on my computer. I cleared some space and it worked!